# How to set a cloudformation parameter to a powershell variable

Tags: powershell, aws-cloudformation

Trying to simply run some powershell in my cloudformation based on a user inpute parameter in cloudformation.

This works

```
write-host ${CFParameter} >> C:\temp\log.txt
```

but this does not

```
$PSVariable = ${CFParameter}

write-host $PSVariable >> C:\temp\log.txt
```

the second one just returns a blank line but the first one returns the correct information

Answer (score 0):

If your powershell is being used in userdata and you can use ref function to refer to the parameter. I would recommend using [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online cloudformation template generator. It makes it easy to generate cloudformation templates.